# How to port a qmake project to cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, qmake, cudd, catkin

I would like to "port" [this C++ project](https://github.com/LTLMoP/slugs), which uses `qmake` (i.e., a [Tool.pro](https://github.com/LTLMoP/slugs/blob/master/src/Tool.pro) file) for building, to `cmake`.

Essentially, I'm asking how to go about writing the necessary `CMakeLists.txt` file(s) by looking at the `Tool.pro` file above.

This is what I've done so far:

```
include_directories(../lib/cudd-2.5.0/include BFAbstractionLibrary)

add_executable(slugs BFAbstractionLibrary/bddDump.cpp BFAbstractionLibrary/BFCuddVarVector.cpp BFAbstractionLibrary/BFCudd.cpp BFAbstractionLibrary/BFCuddManager.cpp \
    BFAbstractionLibrary/BFCuddVarCube.cpp tools.cpp synthesisAlgorithm.cpp synthesisContextBasics.cpp variableManager.cpp \
    BFAbstractionLibrary/BFCuddMintermEnumerator.cpp)

add_library(lcudd ../lib/cudd-2.5.0/cudd)
add_library(ldddmp ../lib/cudd-2.5.0/dddmp)
add_library(lmtr ../lib/cudd-2.5.0/mtr)
add_library(lepd ../lib/cudd-2.5.0/epd)
add_library(lst ../lib/cudd-2.5.0/st)
add_library(lutil ../lib/cudd-2.5.0/util)

target_link_libraries(slugs lcudd, lutil, lmtr, lst, ldddmp, lepd)
```

This is definitely missing the headers that are present in the `Tool.pro` file. I'm also not sure what I have to do with the flags in the first 24 lines of the `Tool.pro` file.

Could you point me in the right direction please?

- PS1. I have already looked at the CMake Tutorial.
- PS2. I have tried
  two scripts: `q2c`, `qmake2cmake`. The former built an essentially
  empty `CMakeLists.txt` file. The latter built a seemingly OK
  file but then `make` failed saying it couldn't find some header file (which is located in a subdirectory).
- PS3. I have successfully built the project with `qmake`.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but are you sure you checked all available resources? The first three results for a standard Google search yield these pretty good-looking resources (sorry, can't format this): http://www.executionunit.com/blog/2014/01/22/moving-from-qmake-to-cmake/            http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:ConvertFromQmake        https://wiki.sofa-framework.org/wiki/SwitchingToCMake

Comment: I've checked the first of the three. I'll take a look at the other two, thanks!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43763416/how-to-convert-qmake-to-cmake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After sacrificing some of the modularity and complexity of the `Tool.pro` file above, I was able to build the project using `cmake`. Here's the `CMakeLists.txt` file that I wrote:

```
project( slugs )

cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 2.6 )

add_definitions ( -Wall )
add_definitions ( -D USE_CUDD )

set ( BDDFLAGS "-mtune=native -malign-double -DHAVE_IEEE_754 -DBSD -DCUDD_COMPILER_OPTIONS_SET" ) # hardcoded for x86_64
add_definitions ( ${BDDFLAGS} )

set ( CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug )
set ( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -g -std=gnu++0x -Wall -Wextra ${BDDFLAGS}")

include_directories ( ../lib/cudd-2.5.0/include BFAbstractionLibrary )

set ( slugs_HDRS
    BFAbstractionLibrary/BF.h
    BFAbstractionLibrary/BFCudd.h
    gr1context.hpp
    variableTypes.hpp
    variableManager.hpp
    extensionExtractExplicitStrategy.hpp
    extensionRoboticsSemantics.hpp
    extensionWeakenSafetyAssumptions.hpp
    extensionBiasForAction.hpp
    extensionComputeCNFFormOfTheSpecification.hpp
    extensionCounterstrategy.hpp
    extensionExtractExplicitCounterstrategy.hpp
    extensionIncrementalSynthesis.hpp
    extensionFixedPointRecycling.hpp
    extensionInteractiveStrategy.hpp
    extensionIROSfastslow.hpp
    extensionAnalyzeInitialPositions.hpp
    extensionAnalyzeAssumptions.hpp
    BFAbstractionLibrary/BFCuddMintermEnumerator.h
    extensionComputeInterestingRunOfTheSystem.hpp
    extensionAnalyzeSafetyLivenessInteraction.hpp
    extensionAbstractWinningTraceGenerator.hpp
    extensionInterleave.hpp
    extensionPermissiveExplicitStrategy.hpp
    extensionIncompleteInformationEstimatorSynthesis.hpp
    extensionNondeterministicMotion.hpp
    extensionExtractSymbolicStrategy.hpp
    extensionTwoDimensionalCost.hpp
    )

set ( slugs_SRCS
    main.cpp
    BFAbstractionLibrary/bddDump.cpp
    BFAbstractionLibrary/BFCuddVarVector.cpp
    BFAbstractionLibrary/BFCudd.cpp
    BFAbstractionLibrary/BFCuddManager.cpp
    BFAbstractionLibrary/BFCuddVarCube.cpp
    tools.cpp
    synthesisAlgorithm.cpp
    synthesisContextBasics.cpp
    variableManager.cpp
    BFAbstractionLibrary/BFCuddMintermEnumerator.cpp
    )

set ( slugs_LIBS
    -L../lib/cudd-2.5.0/cudd
    -L../lib/cudd-2.5.0/util
    -L../lib/cudd-2.5.0/mtr
    -L../lib/cudd-2.5.0/st
    -L../lib/cudd-2.5.0/dddmp
    -L../lib/cudd-2.5.0/epd
    -lcudd
    -ldddmp
    -lmtr
    -lepd
    -lst
    -lutil
    )

add_executable ( slugs ${slugs_SRCS} )

target_link_libraries (slugs ${slugs_LIBS})
```