# How to convert qmake to cmake?

Tags: qt, cmake, qmake

I have a `.pro` file on my project, but now I want to port it to a `CMakeLists.txt` file. How can I do this?

```
QT += core
QT -= gui
CONFIG += c++11
TARGET = test
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
TEMPLATE = app
QT += network
SOURCES += main.cpp \
    test_interface.cpp \
    motomanlibrary.cpp \
    processing.cpp
SOURCES += main.cpp \
    test_interface.h \
    motomanlibrary.h \
    processing.h
```

Comment: http://www.executionunit.com/blog/2014/01/22/moving-from-qmake-to-cmake/

Comment: @Antonio, strange that author of blog post haven't found the way to use Qt Creator along with cmake

Comment: https://wiki.qt.io/CMake_Port/Porting_Guide

Answer (score 43, accepted):

QMake: The required libraries.

```
QT += core
QT -= gui
QT += network
```

CMake: only the add is necessary. An exclude (QT -= gui) is not required.

```
find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Network REQUIRED)
```

QMake: Additional Compiler flags:

```
CONFIG += c++11
```

CMake: Extend the list of compiler flags as required.

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++0x")
```

QMake: The source files

```
SOURCES += main.cpp \
    test_interface.cpp \
    motomanlibrary.cpp \
    processing.cpp
```

CMake: Create a list of source files

```
set(SOURCES
    main.cpp
    test_interface.cpp
    motomanlibrary.cpp
    processing.cpp
)
```

QMake: The header to be included:

```
SOURCES += main.cpp \
    test_interface.h \
    motomanlibrary.h \
    processing.h
```

CMake: Just show where the header files are.

```
include_directory(.) #  or include_directory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
include_directory(some/where/else)
```

QMake: The target to be built:

```
TARGET = test
```

CMake: Set the name of the target, add the sources, link the required libs.

```
add_executable(test ${SOURCES} )
qt5_use_modules(test Core Network) # This macro depends from the Qt version

# Should not be necessary
#CONFIG += console
#CONFIG -= app_bundle
#TEMPLATE = app
```

See further details on [Convert qmake to cmake](http://www.th-thielemann.de/development/cmake/cmake_qmake_to_cmake.html)

Comment: I believe the "new" recommended way to add Qt ilbs to Cmake project is using `target_link_libraries`, eg. `target_link_libraries(test Qt5::Core)` and `target_link_libraries(test Qt5::Network)`, etc.  Ref: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-get-started.html and https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-command-reference.html

Answer (score 11):

There is a python script to convert QMake to CMake on a WIP branch of Qt Base: https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/util/cmake/pro2cmake.py?h=wip/cmake

It will probably be released with Qt 6 when CMake will become the main build system.

Comment: Since is in an alpha stage I didn't use it. I suppose it works by parsing all the `.pro` and `.pri` and converting the QMake keywords to CMake. I think that for simple projects it could work well, but when you start to have multiple modules with `.pro` and maybe an automatic dependencies resolver like QtCreator it may fail!

Comment: I found a small wiki for the module , but not very detailed , see comments.

Comment: In my case `pro2cmake.py` had infinite loop. Turns out it requires `.qmake.conf`, and to bypass such limit, while-loop in `pro2cmake.py:find_qmake_conf` must be modified to stop as soon as `cwd` is the root (I just checked if previous CWD is the same as current to `break` out of the loop).

Comment: now has its own repo at https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qmake2cmake.git/

Answer (score 1):

This is what you would typically write in a simple Qt application built with cmake consuming Qt. A few gotchas:

1. [Use automoc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/AUTOMOC.html). This reduces the maintenance overhead significantly. It is also fast enough even for large projects so that you do not need to care about build-time slow-down.
2. Use [versionless cmake targets](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/cmake-qt5-and-qt6-compatibility.html#versionless-targets) so that they are compatible across Qt versions.
3. If you can, take advantage of the [QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtglobal.html#QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE) variable.
4. As a bonus, enable some usual warning, error and sanitizer detections if you aim for high quality.
5. You may or may not want to add a Qt 5 fallback in case anyone would like to use your software with Qt 5. This requirement may phase out slowly, but surely.

   ```
   project(Application VERSION 1.0.0 LANGUAGES CXX)                                   

   set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)                                                      
   set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)                                             

   set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)                                                           
   set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)                                                           
   set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)                                                           

   find_package(Qt6 COMPONENTS Widgets)                  
   if (NOT Qt6_FOUND)                                                              
     find_package(Qt5 5.15 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)                
   endif()

   if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "(Clang|GNU)")                              
     add_compile_options(-Wall -Wpedantic -Wextra -Werror)                       
     add_compile_options(-fsanitize=address -fsanitize=undefined -fno-omit-frame-pointer)
     add_link_options(-fsanitize=address -fsanitize=undefined -fno-omit-frame-pointer)
   elseif (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "MSVC")                                 
     set_property(DIRECTORY APPEND PROPERTY COMPILE_OPTIONS "/w")                
   endif()                                                                       

   add_compile_definitions(QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0xFFFFFF)

   add_executable(Application                                                                                                                     
     mainwindow.cpp                                                                
     main.cpp                                                                                                                              
   )

   target_link_libraries(Application Qt::Widgets)
   ```