# QTCreator makefile, Cmake, Qmake, Installator

Tags: qt, cmake, installation, qmake

Can I somehow create a normal makefile or use CMake for my QTproject.
I looked up some tutorials and previous questions, but could not find anything.
Is there even a way to make a installer or .deb creator for a QT project?

This is my main concern with Qmake, I need to  create an installer for linux.
I am using Ubuntu.
This is my `Calculator.pro` file:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = Calculator

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp\

mainwindow.cpp\

error.cpp\

mathematics.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h mathematics.h error.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert qmake to cmake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43763416/how-to-convert-qmake-to-cmake)

Comment: This doesn't really answer my core question

Comment: The installer for Linux, if it is possible with qmake

Comment: If your question is `Is there even a way to make a installer or .deb creator for a QT project?`, then why you have CMake in the title and in the tags? A Qt project isn't a CMake project.

Comment: Because all I know is how to make a install. From Cmake